# Unable to start service Intent, U=0: not found (referenceing a library service from the app)

Tags: android, service

I am using a service in my application that is referenced from a local library compiled by my application, and I have placed the service like this in the library's manifest:

```
 <service
            android:name=".backend.service.ConfigurationProcessor"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
```

and I added this in my application manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="io.control.sdk.backend.service.ConfigurationProcessor"
    android:label="io.control.sdk.backend.service.ConfigurationProcessor">

</service>
```

but it doesn't seem to work, Any help?

Comment: Post your build.gradle file and error stack in your question body.

Comment: You mean the build gradle for the app or for the library?

Comment: yes,both of them.